# Почему ничего не выводится? Надо перевернуть массив

Tags: c++

Надо перевернуть массив на промежутке K - L. Ввожу массив [1 2 3 4 5], K=2, L=4;
Вот код:

```
    for(int i=L-1; i<K-1; i--)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
```

Но почему ничего не выводится? Где ошибка? Я не вижу его =/

Answer (score 7):

посмотрите на условия выхода с цикла. Учитывая, что `K < L`, оно будет ложно при первой итеррации.

```
for(int i=L-1; i>=K-1; i--)
{
    cout << arr[i] << " ";
}
```

нужно поменять условие на противоположное. хотя нужно почитать условие точнее, может там и просто `>` достаточно. Все зависит от того, как интерпретировать диапазон.

Comment: ох уж эти мелкие ошибки! Спасибо!